# Please HELP. On Ubuntu: error-monitoring consume my CPU

Tags: cpu

Since yesterday, my Ubuntu desktop fan has gone berserk. So I turned it off. I thought it would kill what ever causing it. Today, I turned it on again and the fan still goes wild. So I ran `top` and found that a process called `errors-monitoring` is using 800% of my CPU! How can I find out what causes the error that make this program go crazy?

I've reviewed the log but didn't find anything suspicious.

**Updated:** Here is the picture.
[image]

**Updated 2:** Here is the picture of the system monitor's property of the process.
[image]

It seems to relate to docker.

Comment: It's showing 800% because you have 8 CPU's running at 100%. I googled `errors-monitoring` and there are no exact hits. Are you sure the spelling is exactly that?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping. 'top' only shows 'error-monitori' but 'ps ax' shows 'error-monitoring' for the same PID. I am not sure about 's' after error; I will check when I can and will get back to you (should be in about an hour). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find more information about the process is via System Monitor:

`System Monitor` → `Processes` → `[Right-Click]` → `Properties`

Comment: Please see the picture in the updated. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Docker (it's on my to-learn list). I would suggest submitting a new question about it.